# ASP.NET's App_Code Folder and Shared/Static Classes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

If I have a 'Shared' object defined in the App_Code folder; is that object shared amongst all users/visitors of my website?  Or is it shared on a per-user basis?

I don't know if that makes sense or not; but I've got a puzzle/solver I'd written earlier that I'm trying to incorporate into a simple ASP.Net site.  It's probably poorly written, but I'd used a Shared boolean to determine if a solution had been found.  The code works, now as an ASP.NET site, but if two visitors to my site were both validating their puzzle at the same time, would they both be accessing the same boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your variable is static then all user will access that same variable and any change to that variable will effect all users in case of web-application only, the logic is when your are making a variable static then a memory location is allocated in server when this location is allocated all users share that location only because it is static.

Answer (score 1):

Static variable are shared amongst all the users / across the application. I have tested this in one of my projects.  I am 100% sure your Boolean variable value will be shared among all users

Answer (score 1):

*Static* members are shared between all users of the WebApplication.

You might need to reed the following article. It contains some usefull information about *Application State* variables and *Static* members:

[Application Instances, Application Events, and Application State in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q312607)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, IIS may clone your application into multiple AppDomains. Though your static variables will be shared amongst all users (or threads) on the same AppDomain, it won't be shared if they are on separate AppDomains.